# Strange effect using 'distort perspective' on multiple images using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, perspective, distortion

I want to create a 3D effect on an image so it looks like a folder, using the +distort Perspective' commands from ImageMagick.

However, if I use the distort multiple times (on different layers) in ImageMagick the result doesn't look correct.

Please see the attached image, left is correct, but the top-right corner of the right image looks strange.

[image: left is correct but right is incorrect]

I have used the following commands:

```
convert square.jpg -brightness-contrast 0x0 -resize 700x700 \
            \( -clone 0 -flip -crop 700x140+0-0 -size 700x140 gradient:gray60-black -compose CopyOpacity -composite \) \
            -append front.png

convert square.jpg -brightness-contrast -50x0 -resize 700x700 \
\( -clone 0 -flip -crop 700x140+0-0 -size 700x140 gradient:gray60-black -compose CopyOpacity -composite \) \
-append inner.png

convert -background None -virtual-pixel transparent -background white  \
            \( inner.png +distort Perspective '0,0 0,0  700,0 735,-35  700,700 735,665  0,700 0,700' \) \
            \( front.png +distort Perspective '0,0 0,0  700,0 665,35  700,700 665,735  0,700 0,700' \) \
            -layers merge +repage 3dimage.jpg
```

I'm using ImageMagick v6.8

I'm not sure if I understand the layers in ImageMagick correctly. 
Can someone see what's wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure if I understand the layers in ImageMagick correctly. Can someone see what's wrong?

You're doing fine. Just need to repeat the `-virtual-pixel transparent` on the sub-image for front.png *(and perhaps the inner.png too)*.

```
convert -background None -virtual-pixel transparent -background white  \
        \( inner.png +distort Perspective '0,0 0,0  700,0 735,-35  700,700 735,665  0,700 0,700' \) \
        \( front.png -virtual-pixel transparent +distort Perspective '0,0 0,0  700,0 665,35  700,700 665,735  0,700 0,700' \) \
        -layers merge +repage 3dimage.jpg
```

[image: 3dimage.jpg]

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Adding the virtual-pixel for the front.png did the job. I assumed the -virtual-pixel setting was preserved for the whole command.